# design a counter from 0-3 in java without %

Tags: java

I need a code in java that prints 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 without %.
I know the ans in c,but is there a equivalent program in java.

```
#include "stdio.h"
struct m
{
    unsigned int a:2;
}mm;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i\n",mm.a++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course there is an equivalent in Java, you just need to write it?

Comment: `a = a > 2 ? 0 : a + 1`

Comment: Your C version will print "0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 ..." and not "0 1 2 0 1 2 ...".

Comment: Your question should be more specific. What are you trying to accomplish exactly. If you want a simple integer variable to automatically perfrom moduo x on itself when you update it's value, afaik you can't do that in Java. You can build custom logic to accomplish the same. Why would you specifically not use the moduo operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C version does not print "0 1 2 0 1 2 ...". It prints "0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 ..." instead.

If you want a Java program that does what your C version really does:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i & 3);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave figuring out how it works up to you.

Comment: sorry for that,i want to print 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 .using the same method as in c program

Comment: Java does not have bit fields like in C, so it is not possible to do it in exactly the same way as in C.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how to print

```
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

in Java without using the % operator?
Sure, easy enough:

```
System.out.println("0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2");
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i agre the first sentence **is** a comment. But the rest is a straightforward answer to the posted question. I'll make the appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you a code for Print 0 1 2 0 1 2 in Java? What I've known.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        x = x + 1;
        if(x > 2){
            x = 0;
         }            
       }
    }    
 }
```